# Jest React Native, testing / mocking? onLayout

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I currently have this relatively simply screen in React, that I need to test in Jest, however, I'm not terribly familiar with the library and this is what I've got so far.

Things I'd like to test?

The onLayoutEvent. Does this need mocked?
Showing / hiding of the spinner on page. At the moment, it finds it here: (which is fine)

```
expect(spinner).not.toBeNull();
```

But still finds it after the event call, whereas in actual fact it is hidden by state after the event fires.

Loading for this component occurs from a call to setLoading in it's children. I've also zero clue on how to test this. Any assistance on what / how to test this component appreciated.

```
describe('Login', () => {
  test('it should render', () => {
    renderWithStore(<LoginStarter />);
  });

  test('it should fire a layout event', async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = renderWithStore(<LoginStarter />);
    const view = await getByTestId('loginId');
    const spinner = await getByTestId('loginSpinner');
    expect(spinner).not.toBeNull();

    act(() =>
      fireEvent(view, 'onLayout', {
        nativeEvent: { layout: { width: 500 } },
      }),
    );
  });
});
```

The core component

```
 const [widthLoading, setWidthLoading] = useState(true);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [containerWidth, setContainerWidth] = useState<number>();

  const onLayout = (event: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
    const { width } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    setContainerWidth(width);
    setWidthLoading(false);
  };

  const tabs = [
    {
      title: 'Login',
      component: () => LoginScreen({ componentId: props.componentId, setLoading }),
      testID: 'tab1',
    },
    {
      title: 'Sign up',
      component: () => RegisterScreen({ componentId: props.componentId, setLoading }),
      testID: 'tab2',
    },
  ];

  const wrapperStyle = {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    opacity: loading ? 0.5 : 1,
  };

  const loadingStyle = {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
  };

  return (
    <View testID="loginId" onLayout={onLayout} style={wrapperStyle as StyleProp<ViewStyle>}>
      {loading && (
        <View style={loadingStyle as StyleProp<ViewStyle>}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={theme.spinner} />
        </View>
      )}
      <View>
        {!widthLoading && containerWidth ? (
          <Tabs style="light" tabWidth={Math.round(containerWidth / 2)} tabs={tabs} tabsScrollEnabled />
        ) : (
          <ActivityIndicator testID="loginSpinner" size="large" color={theme.spinner} />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with testing `onLayout` as well. One thing I will point out is that in your code

```js
act(() =>
  fireEvent(view, 'onLayout', {
    nativeEvent: { layout: { width: 500 } },
  }),
);
```

`onLayout` should actually just be `layout`. I dug into the library code and found this:

```js
const toEventHandlerName = eventName => `on${eventName.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${eventName.slice(1)}`;
```

Also, you don't need to wrap `fireEvent` with `act` as it is wrapped by `act` by default. As per the docs:

> Act: Useful function to help testing components that use hooks API. By default any render, update, fireEvent, and waitFor calls are wrapped by this function, so there is no need to wrap it manually.

All that said, I still can't get onLayout to fire.

**Edit:** 

The above actually was triggering the `onLayout` for me. It was the was I was spying on `useState` that was my issue.